# Undefined method 'getCategories'. The method name must start with either findBy, findOneBy or countBy

Tags: symfony4

In Categories enity, there're annotations:

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoriesRepository")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
```

In CategoriesRepository, there is:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\SomeRepository;

class CategoriesRepository extends SomeRepository
{
      public function getCategories($id,...)
}
```

In the CategoriesController, there is:

```
namespace App\Controller;

public function indexAction(Request $request, $id, ...)
{
     $categoriesRepository = $this->em->getRepository('App:Categories');
     $list = $categoriesRepository->getCategories($id,...);
}
```

Why is there an error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it instead has to be:

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoriesRepository")
```